# Updated strings are not reflecting in my files

Tags: unix

After using the below command to replace the every even number occurrence of the 'ims' to 'ims2' in my files. Updated strings are not saved or reflected in my files. Can you please help?

Below is the command i have used:

```
awk -i 'ims' '{for (i=1; i<NF; i++) {OFS=c%2?"ims2":FS; printf "%s%s", $i, OFS; c++}
print $NF}' ARCM_UODS_ITE21062018045802_CDUSACGCANTS00002.csv
```

Comment: Do you mean `-F 'ims' ` instead of `'ims' ` ?

Comment: i mean "ims" should be replaced with "ims2" at even numbered occurence of ims value in a file. and file should be saved with the updated values.

Comment: my requirement is to replace string "ims" value with "ims2" at even numbered occurence. for eg: ims, ims,ims,ims then output should be ims,ims2,ims,im2. this should happen inside file

Comment: I understand. But in order to set "ims" as the field separator, you either need to assign it to `FS` or use the `-F` option. I was asking if you meant to have `awk -i -F 'ims'` instead of `awk -i ims` .